# What is the second argument of $parse() for?

Tags: angularjs

Today, I ran into this while looking at [ngOptions.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngOptions.js) source:

```
getWatchables: $parse(valuesFn, function(values) {
        // Create a collection of things that we would like to watch (watchedArray)
        // so that they can all be watched using a single $watchCollection
        // that only runs the handler once if anything changes
        var watchedArray = [];
        values = values || [];

        Object.keys(values).forEach(function getWatchable(key) {
          var locals = getLocals(values[key], key);
          var label = displayFn(scope, locals);
          var selectValue = getTrackByValue(values[key], locals);
          watchedArray.push(selectValue);
          watchedArray.push(label);
        });
        return watchedArray;
      }),
```

but the official documentation for [$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) doesn't specify any second argument.

What does it do ?

Comment: if you look at the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js#L956) it is some kind of interceptor function that can use or manipulate the parsed expressing value. In this case, it gets the value and turns it in to a collection of watched objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sources**

v1.3.4:

```
function addInterceptor(parsedExpression, interceptorFn) {
  if (!interceptorFn) return parsedExpression;
  var watchDelegate = parsedExpression.$$watchDelegate;

  var regularWatch =
      watchDelegate !== oneTimeLiteralWatchDelegate &&
      watchDelegate !== oneTimeWatchDelegate;

  var fn = regularWatch ? function regularInterceptedExpression(scope, locals) {
    var value = parsedExpression(scope, locals);
    return interceptorFn(value, scope, locals);
  } : function oneTimeInterceptedExpression(scope, locals) {
    var value = parsedExpression(scope, locals);
    var result = interceptorFn(value, scope, locals);
    // we only return the interceptor's result if the
    // initial value is defined (for bind-once)
    return isDefined(value) ? result : value;
  };

  // Propagate $$watchDelegates other then inputsWatchDelegate
  if (parsedExpression.$$watchDelegate &&
      parsedExpression.$$watchDelegate !== inputsWatchDelegate) {
    fn.$$watchDelegate = parsedExpression.$$watchDelegate;
  } else if (!interceptorFn.$stateful) {
    // If there is an interceptor, but no watchDelegate then treat the interceptor like
    // we treat filters - it is assumed to be a pure function unless flagged with $stateful
    fn.$$watchDelegate = inputsWatchDelegate;
    fn.inputs = [parsedExpression];
  }

  return fn;
}
```

According to the sample above and sources of angularjs the second argument allows you to apply *transform-like* logic to the result of parse.

Look at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngOptions.js#L461:

```
// We will re-render the option elements if the option values or labels change
scope.$watchCollection(ngOptions.getWatchables, updateOptions);
```

Seems, it is used to provide single way for a watch in sources of ngOptions. It triggers on changes of name and/or label. If it will not be used the watch would work only for changes of label or only for changes of value, not both.

**Other samples of use in angular code**

*1. Watch of ng-bind*

```
  var ngBindHtmlWatch = $parse(tAttrs.ngBindHtml, function getStringValue(value) {
    return (value || '').toString();
  });
```

Here we construct a watch based on $parse value transformed to the string. Seems for better and simple comparation in $digest cycle.

*2. The watch in '='-scoped parameters of a directive*

```
var parentValueWatch = function parentValueWatch(parentValue) {
  if (!compare(parentValue, isolateBindingContext[scopeName])) {
  // we are out of sync and need to copy
  if (!compare(parentValue, lastValue)) {
  // parent changed and it has precedence
  isolateBindingContext[scopeName] = parentValue;
  } else {
  // if the parent can be assigned then do so
  parentSet(scope, parentValue = isolateBindingContext[scopeName]);
}
}
return lastValue = parentValue;
};
```

As you see we just keep scope values in sync based on dirty checks. It is why we need a second $digest-cycle to trigger internal watches of the directive.

---

**Summary**

Seems it is a way to transform from something heavy to an easy thing which one should be comparable by simple `=` in $digest-cycle. It is needed to conclude should we trigger a watch or not.

Also it might be used as a way to place common logic for watches. It allows to write them once and use for all cases when we need $parsed value.